# Is this "had" necessary?

Tags: past-perfect

I went to the disaster zone last year. It had been 12 years since the tragedy **had** happened.

Is this "had" – the one just after the word *tragedy* – necessary?

Answer (score 9):

*Had been* creates a past perfect construction which accomplishes at least two things:

- It establishes clearly that the tragedy occurred 12 years before you went to the disaster zone, not twelve years before the present.
- It establishes the "Reference Time" for your discourse—the time where your discourse will be "anchored"— at the time you went to the disaster area, rather than in the present, while permitting you to move coherently between the two past events, the tragedy and your visit.

*Had happened* is not strictly necessary to establish the sequence—you may, and in conversation probably would, use a simple past, or simply omit the verb altogether—but it reinforces location of Reference Time at the time of your visit. This will not be a discourse about the tragedy or about your present experience, but about the impact of the tragedy on what you saw and experienced when you visited.

You may read a great deal more about the meaning and use of perfect constructions at [**Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), particularly sections [**3.1**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13260/32) (*What does the perfect* mean?*—Grammatical Meaning*), [**3.2**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32)  (*What does the perfect* mean?*—Pragmatic Meaning*), and [**4**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it/13262#13262) (*How and when should I use the perfect?*).

Comment: Thank you. But I wasn't talking about the first had but the second. Since the tragedy "had" happened.

Comment: @birdman1234 My apologies; I stupidly overlooked your perfectly plain emphasis. I have added a paragraph to address this.

Comment: Thumbs up to @birdman for pressing the point! The second *had* is indeed "not strictly necessary", and on purely stylistic grounds I suspect most *speakers* would avoid it (because it makes the whole utterance rather "ponderous"). But in some (literary?) contexts it can definitely be justified (because it reinforces the location of Reference Time, not because it echoes/balances the first *had*).

Comment: @StoneyB Thank you. It's possible to say "It was 12 years since the tragedy happened.?"

Comment: @birdman1234 You can. I don't much like it, but that's personal.

Answer (score 1):

The second instance of *had* is unnecessary. *Happened* communicates a past event, making it  redundant.

Words should improve communication. Density, specificity, and readability are the important characteristics. Eliminate the word and test the result, if it doesn't increase one of those characteristics, eliminate it. For example:

*It had been 12 years since the tragedy happened.*

Did the sentence lose density, specificity, or readability?
The density was increased, readability improved, and specificity unchanged, so the result is an improvement.

Furthermore, *since* communicates that the *12 years* is referring to a period of time between two events. *Since* and *tragedy* are therefore both event based, rendering the information in the word *happened* redundant. Let's try a further reduction:

*It had been 12 years since the tragedy.*

Even better.

It communicates that 12 years elapsed between the tragedy and the event. All of the information using fewer words equals improved communication.

Comment: I'm a bit uneasy about "between the tragedy and the event" there. All we know is that "the tragedy" predates "it" by 12 years - that's the "existential **it**", which may not correspond to any particular "event" at all. All "it" represents is the "Reference Time", as per StoneyB's answer.